# How to open combo box of Datagridview cell from the first click

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have DataGridView whith Column of comboboxes.

I have to click twice the cell in order combo to be opened.

Anyone knows how may I make it to be opened from the first click.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct access to DataGridView combobox in one click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445070/direct-access-to-datagridview-combobox-in-one-click)

Comment: You may want to check [this solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543940/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-doesnt-open-the-dropdown-on-first-click/39757746#39757746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Check below links it will help you
```

[Direct access to DataGridView combobox in one click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445070/direct-access-to-datagridview-combobox-in-one-click)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/a5acbaf3-9d80-4d0c-8c7d-77eea7d4efd0

Comment: Expand your answer as link only answers are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier way:

In the CellEnter event, check if the column index corresponds with the combobox column. If it does, set

```
DataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

or if it's a regular column, set it to the default

```
DataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;
```